# Is there a way to put a line break after every line?

Tags: html, css, copy, line-breaks

I am making a documentation page, I am trying to paste text into an html paragraph and want to keep the format. When paste the text below into my html it is displayed all bunched together. How can I put a line break after every line?

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  console.log("starting slow promise")
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("slow")
      console.log("slow promise is done")
    }, 2000)
  })
}

function resolveAfter1Second() {
  console.log("starting fast promise")
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("fast")
      console.log("fast promise is done")
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the pre tag to keep formatting as written

```html
<pre>
this is 
   an example
        of how to use the pre tag
 </pre>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: if this works for you please accept answer as correct, thanks